# Can I measure branch-prediction failures on a modern Intel Core CPU?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, optimization, branch-prediction

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) and its answer, which was recently tagged as an Epic Answer, has prompted me to wonder; Can I measure the performance of a running application in Windows in terms of its CPU branch prediction failures?  I know that some static analysis tools exist, that might help with optimizing code for good performance in branch-prediction situations, and that manual techniques could help by simply making changes and re-testing, but I'm looking for some automatic mechanism that can report a total number of branch prediction failures, over a period of time, as a Windows application runs, and I'm hoping that some Profiler tool for Visual C++ could help me.

For the sake of this question, the application in question is either built with a native-compiler such as Visual C++ for Windows, or using some other native compiler, such as GCC, FreePascal, Delphi, or TurboAssembler. The executable may not have any debug information at all. I want to know if I can detect, and count branch prediction failures, perhaps by reading internal CPU information through some Windows service like WMI, or perhaps by running entirely inside a virtualized environment running Windows, such as using VirtualBox, and then running a completely virtualized windows environment with my test application, inside VirtualBox, and doing runtime analysis of the virtual CPU. Or some other technique that I don't know of, thus this question.

Yes, I googled.  The only thing that looks promising is [this PDF](http://developer.amd.com/Assets/intro_to_ca_v3_final.pdf) from AMD. Page 18 mentions something very close to what I'd like to do, but seems written for those working without any operating system, on raw evaluation hardware platforms:

> 5.1. Branches.  Applicability. Conditional branch mispredictions may be a significant issue in code with a lot of  decision-making logic.
>
> Conditional branches may be mispredicted when the likelihood of
>   choosing  the true or false path is random or near a 50-50 split.  The
>   branch prediction hardware cannot  "learn" a pattern and branches are
>   not predicted correctly.  Collection. Collect the events in this table
>   to measure branch prediction performance:
>
> Branches  Compute the rate at which branches are
>   taken and the ratio of the number of instructions per  branch using
>   these formulas:    Branch taken rate = Taken_branches /
>   Ret_instructions    Branch taken ratio = Taken_branches / Branches
>   Instructions per branch = Ret_instructions / Branches

Update: I guess I could say I'm looking for a way to read the Intel Core i7 PMU module, or equivalent functions of other CPUs. It looks like Intel VTUNE (from the comments by Adrian) is very close to what I asked for.

Comment: I'm not confident enough to put this in an answer, but I think VTune from Intel would be able to tell you about missed branch predictions, at least if you're profiling on an Intel processor.

Comment: This?  ( http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe/ ) -- wow. Looks impressive.  For just a PMU-reader, it looks like there's THIS too: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor/

Comment: @Adrian McCarthy: to my knowledge that's right. vTune is quite impressive, although not inexpensive. Unfortunately the limitation to Intel CPUs can be an issue in many use cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VTune Performance Analyzer can do it! Btw if you are studying these topics, take a look at "Optimization Cookbook" from Intel Press.

Note: Comments state the same answer but with some uncertainty, I used VTune and I measured the branch prediction rate for an Intel CPU. So I'm 100% sure.

[here is the link for VTune](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-vtune-performance-analyzer/)

[here is the link for the book](http://www.intel.com/intelpress/sum_swcb2.htm)

Comment: The book link is outdated unfortunately, but thanks for the reference!