# Starting a function with a branch

Tags: c++, branch-prediction

From optimization and branch predictor point of view, is there any difference between those two codes?

**First:**

```
void think_and_do(){
    if(expression){
        //Set_A of instructions
    }
    else{
         //Set_B of instructions
    }
}

int main(){
    think_and_do();
}
```

**Second:**

```
void do_A(){
    //Set_A of instructions
}

void do_B(){
    //Set_B of instructions
}

int main(){
    if(expression){
        do_A();
    }
    else{
        do_B();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would think you would get the same code but it depends on the compiler an optimization settings.  You could compile both and check the assembly.

Comment: this seems to be a question best answered empirically. iterate a few million times over some repeatable pseudo-random data, and [measure it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437523/can-i-measure-branch-prediction-failures-on-a-modern-intel-core-cpu?rq=1).

Comment: One key could be the number of the parameters needed for both functions. First case the function `think_and_do()` needed to have all parameters and Second case only the function `do_A()` or `do_B()` needs all parameters (typically when `do_A()` creates an object and `do_B()` deletes this object).

Answer (score 3):

I've made an test on godbolt.org [think_and_do](https://godbolt.org/g/h9fjAo) and in [main](https://godbolt.org/g/bjsIZO)

First observation, if your examples are trivial they mostly get optimized away. Without the `cin` both examples should have compiled to:

```
    xor     eax, eax
    add     rsp, 8 #may or may not be present.
    ret
```

Second observation is that the code is exactly the same in main: and none of the functions are called, everything is inlined.

Third observation is that both examples makes the following code

```
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR a[rip]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR b[rip]
    cmp     edx, eax
    je      .L8
```

That is they fill one cycle of 4 instruction to make the most of issuing (and ignore the possibility of macro-fusion of the cmp and jump).

If they had started with an

```
    cmp     edx, eax
    je      .L8
```

Half of the issue bandwidth would potentially have been wasted.

Comment: I think the point was about cases where you can't inline the function

Comment: @Leeor And the conclusion is that the compiler does inline for you even if you dont specify it, which makes it no difference.